# Can you Change a field in a Parent model when creating a Child/Kid model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and C# so please forgive my question if it is silly or basic to anyone out there:

### I am trying to write a program with the following classes

```
public class Parent 
{
    public int ParentID {get;set;}
    public string Name  {get;set;}
    public string Status {get; set;}  

    // Status changed to Grandparent if any of their kids has a kid

    public virtual ICollection<Kid> Kids {get;set;}  //"Linked list" of Parent's Kids
}

public class Kid
{
    public int KidID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public int ParentID {get;set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get;set;}     // Link back to Parent Entity
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
In a controller for the Kid, it looks like something like this
..
// GET: Create Kid

public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ParentID = new SelectList(db.Problem, "ParentID", "Name");
    return View();
}

// POST: Create Kid

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create (Kid kid)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        switch (kid.LifeEvent)
        {
            case X:  blah blah
            break;
            case Y:  blah blah
            break;
            case 1: kid.Parent.Status = "GrandParent";
            break;
         } 
     }
...
```

The problem i am having is that (In Kid Controller) the "Parent" value in kid.Parent.Status is always NULL, the program always crashes at the case

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Kid view doesnt have a way to save the parent information. You may use hidden field or something similar on the Kid view to store the Parent object something like

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Parent.ParentID)

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Parent.Status])

}

// do the same for all properties u need

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried the code and the Parent field is still Null.  I will keep trying